# how to show multiple images on bootstarap model by passing object in image parameter

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

```
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view" class="Pop" image="
<%-value.imageList%>"></a>
```

value.imageList is a object from db 
i am passing object of multiple image url to bootstap model. how to show all images on single model? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this post first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And post some code that you have written so far

Comment: What will you have in image attribute? Will it be a string or json or an array?

Comment: it is json coming from db